# jQuery-File-Upload do not load file name to input and can not trigger by another button

Tags: jquery, file-upload

plugin:https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I don't want this plugin autoupload after select file.
So I follow [how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click), but do not work. 
And it doesn't show file name after I select a file.

```
<input id="fileupload" class="fileupload" type="file" name="import_file"  data-url="{% url 'staff_member_address_import' %}" />
<button type="submit" class="import_btn btn blue">import </button>
```

js:

```
var uploader = $("#fileupload");
uploader.fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    //formData: {
    //    example: 'test'
    //},
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('.import_btn').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var file_name = $('input[name="import_file"]').val();
            if (!file_name) {
                alert('must select one file');
                return;
            }

            if (file_name.split('.')[file_name.split('.').length-1] != 'csv') {
                alert('wrong file');
                return;
            }
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        if(data.status =='OK'){
            alert('OK！');
        }else{
            alert('fail');
        }
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it uploading with the button, I am doing this (got it from another SO post). As you can see I am moving the file check logic outside of the click event, it checks the file the moment you select it in your file input.

```
$(".import_btn").unbind('click').on('click', function() {
  data.submit();
});

add: function (e, data) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var file_name = $('input[name="import_file"]').val();
  if (!file_name) {
    alert('must select one file');
      return;
  }

  if (file_name.split('.')[file_name.split('.').length-1] != 'csv') {
    alert('wrong file');
    return;
  }

  $('.import_btn').on('click', function(e){      
    data.submit();
  });
}, (...)
```

It is uploading the file when I click, but it is not showing the file when I select it.